# Oracle Backup procedure

Tags: oracle

I'am trying to set up backup of Oracle DBMS.

Content init.ora file:

```
log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=<location>';
log_archive_dest_state_1=ENABLE;
log_archive_format='%t_%s_%r.arc' scope=spfile
```

I executed the following commands:

```
alter database archivelog;
alter system archive log start;
alter system archive log current;
alter database create standby controlfile as '<location>';
```

Then, I copied the created log files (.arc), control file (.ctl) and data files (.dbf) to the replica.

Content init.ora on replica:

```
log_archive_dest_1='LOCATION=<location>'
log_archive_dest_state_1=ENABLE
log_archive_format=%t_%s_%r.arc
control_files='<location>'
STANDBY_FILE_MANAGEMENT=AUTO
compatible ='11.2.0'
```

I executed the following commands on the replica:

```
startup nomount
alter database mount standby database;
recover standby database;
alter database open;
```

But I get error:

```
ORA-10458: standby database requires recovery
ORA-01194: file 1 needs more recovery to be consistent
ORA-01110: data file 1: filename.dbf'
```

Someone with such already faced, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, if you are trying to build standby database, you may just open database for read only.

```
alter database open read only;
```

I would recommend you to check [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/data-guard#SetupStandbyDatabase) article for your reference